# How to separate one column to multiple using conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want separate one column into multiple columns based on condition.

Table : emp

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([name], [id]) 
VALUES (N'lux-pen-oxo-mobile', 1), 
       (N'pne-soap', 2),
       (N'hop-pen-mobile-soap-jad', 3),
       (N'pen-soap-box', 4)
```

Based on the above data I want output like below :

```
id  |prod1  |prod2   |prod3   |prod4    | Prod5
1   |lux    |pen     |oxo     |mobile   |   
2   |pne    |soap    |        |         |
3   |hop    |pen     |mobile  |soap     |jad    
4   |pen    |soap    |box     |
```

I tried like this:

```
select  
    id,
    case 
       when charindex('-', name) > 0 
          then substring(name, 1, charindex('-', [name]) - 1) 
    end prod1,
    substring(name, charindex('-', [name], 2) + 1, len(name)) prod2,
    substring(name, charindex('-', [name], 3) + 1, len(name)) prod3,
    substring(name, charindex('-', [name], 4) + 1, len(name)) prod4,
    substring(name, charindex('-', [name], 5) + 1, len(name)) prod4 
from 
    [emp]
```

This query not returning the expected result.

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Normalization is the key

Comment: Your simplest solution is probably a dynamic query (for an unknown number of hyphens) with a recursive CTE or a string-split function (to parse the strings for each part). Unless 5 is the most, in which case you don't need it to be dynamic. But as the above comment points out, you should be normalising your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `CTE` like following example.

```
;WITH Split_Names (ID,xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT ID,      
    CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>'  
    + REPLACE(Name,'-', '</name><name>') + '</name></Names>') AS xmlname
      FROM [dbo].[emp]
)

SELECT ID,      
xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS prod1,    
xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS prod2,
xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') AS prod3,
xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[4]','varchar(100)') AS prod4,
xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[5]','varchar(100)') AS prod5   
FROM Split_Names
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | prod1 | prod2 | prod3  | prod4  | prod5 |
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  | lux   | pen   | oxo    | mobile | NULL  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2  | pne   | soap  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| 3  | hop   | pen   | mobile | soap   | jad   |
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| 4  | pen   | soap  | box    | NULL   | NULL  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
```

If you want to replace `NULL` with `''`, in that case you can change the columns in select like following.

```
ISNULL(xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)'),'') AS prod1  ,
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/IOROO86937)

Comment: Hi above query is working fine.is it possible to achieve this task using substring and charindex functions

Comment: it can be achieved, but it will be more complex, with XML, it is more clean.